# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot connect to a certain wifi while my iphone can

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, networkmanager

this is my first post here so if there are something wrong about this post, please tell me.

I’m now working in Tokyo, and the office offers a wifi. While my iphone is able to connect to it, my new clean ubuntu 18.04 cannot. Also, before I reinstalled the ubuntu, it can, too. (previous ubuntu version is the same, 18.04)

When I select the office wifi from the panel, originally the ‘hotspot login’ window pop up and be connected after login.

But now the window shows up with error message
“Error resolving ‘xxx.xxx.jp’: name or service not known”.

I suspected it is a DNS issue so I have edited the /etc/network/interfaces and use 8.8.8.8 as a dns-nameserver. And now when I ping google.com it gives me its ip address. But I still cannot find the ip of ‘xxx.xxx.jp’.

Also, I can use my phone (already connected to the office wifi) to browse ‘xxx.xxx.jp/aaa/bbb/index.html’ (the login page). However even when the Ubuntu cannect to iphone hotspot, it cannot browser the login page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: at the end, I ask my colleague for the ip address of xxx.xxx.jp. Looks like a DNS issue.

Answer (score 1):

To access a local DNS name you must use the local network DNS server that is resolving these local Host names.

use "nmcli" to determine what DNS addresses you are using for resolution.

```
nmcli device show <interfacename> | grep IP4.DNS
```

This basically just means that you need to use the DNS servers provided by DHCP.

Most captive portal pages use a DNS name for redirection. If you can't resolve the DNS name you won't be able to hit the captive portal/radius server to login.

Comment: When my iphone is connected to the wifi, I can see the dns ip, and that’s the same ip when I use the command you suggested. But ubuntu can’t still find the ip of the name.

Comment: No, I didn’t change it, also ufw is disabled. Also tried iptables -F, didn’t work. Thank you.

Comment: actually there was no 8.8.8.8 in the original /etc/network/interfaces, so I added it. But since it's not working, I removed it. Now the file looks like "auto lo" and "iface lo inet loopback"

Comment: so you are suggesting adding "<interface_name> auto" into the file?

Comment: Yes, I've seen that post and it didn't work. Really strange..

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux this has some examples of modifying the netplan settings